# Whilst making ERD's in a recursive relationship does it always have to link N to N or can it be N to 0 or 1?

Tags: erd, der

The title sums it up pretty much, needing help with it to continue with my ERD for my class. The instructions the teacher gave were:

It is intended to keep information about the albums (title, year, comment, compilation) being relevant to keep the respective nationality, musical genre, as well as the artists who participate in it.
• Artists can be a person or a group and are characterized by a name and type of artist. It is also important to know who the artists that make up the group are.
• The artists' participation in the album implies the indication if the participation is the main role or not, as well as the type of intervention (instrument) that each artist has in the album.

I currently have it linked like this

https://gyazo.com/1b1a8ef130906c875e888ec0eb46bf09

As per the instructions I have the main role part, but I thought it could be a relation instead of an entity and would link back to the artist N to 0 or 1...

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question simply - NO it dont have to be N...N
the idea of recursive relationships is that you can 'bundle' entities of same structure that interacts with each other to simplify the ERD.

### e.g. the Employee vs Supervisor example :)

IF it could only be N...N

- N Employees would always be overseen by N Supervisors.

but in most cases N Employee is overseen by 1 Supervisors, which is also an employee, therefor you can write your recursive relation on the ERD as N..X